# Override deleted_at when searching with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In some cases, I would like to specify that my ActiveRecord results should include items where deleted_at is not null.

For example, say I search for the following deleted record:

```
 item =Item.find(12345)
```

I get this result:

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Item with id=12345 [WHERE ("items"."deleted_at" IS NULL)]
```

Is it possible to set a parameter that returns active record items where the deleted_at value is not null?

Comment: This behavior is not native to Rails, so I assume you're using a "soft delete" gem like paranoia or ActsAsParanoid. We need to know which gem it is in order to answer your question (although you can probably find the answer in the gem's documentation).

Answer (score 6):

You can disable all scopes by applying 'unscoped' method to your model, like:

```
item = Item.unscoped.find(12345)
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#removing-all-scoping